# Order in taking density matrix trace

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, density-operator, trace

I remember that for infinite dimensional Hilbert space, the trace is not cyclic, for example, for harmonic oscillators, then we have
$$Tr(aa^{\dagger})\neq Tr(a^{\dagger}a)$$
Then, when we calculate the ensemble average in quantum statistics mechanics, for example, the average occupation number, which one should we us?
$Tr(\rho a^{\dagger}a)$ or $Tr(a^{\dagger}a \rho)$?

Comment: Can you perform this calculation explicitly for the harmonic oscillator ? And if so, comment on the meaning of the result.

Comment: The density matrix regularizes the answers, so they are no longer infinite, unlike your first “inequality”.

Comment: @Martin There is no specific density matrix I have in mind. This is just a random question that comes to my mind. Actually, in practice,  for all density matrix I encountered , the cyclic property works pretty well. But I just do not know whether this is the general case